# Swift image from URL not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm new to swift and not sure why an image is loading from the url.
The code:

```
        let url = NSURL(string: imageURL)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        println("Should load the pic!")
        var profilePic = UIImage(data: data)
        self.profileImage.setImage(profilePic)
    })
```

In my interface controller I have an image called "profileImage" that is linked with an IBOutlet. One thing I noticed is that "Should load the pic!" does not appear in the console so it is not getting to the setImage code..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you downloading image from URL. I suggest you to do this in background. here is the example code for you:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    profileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com/euro/ios/ios8/a/generic/images/og.png") {
        downloadImage(checkedUrl)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func getDataFromUrl(urL:NSURL, completion: ((data: NSData?) -> Void)) {
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urL) { (data, response, error) in
        completion(data: NSData(data: data))
        }.resume()
}

func downloadImage(url:NSURL){
    println("Started downloading \"\(url.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension)\".")
    getDataFromUrl(url) { data in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            println("Finished downloading \"\(url.lastPathComponent!.stringByDeletingPathExtension)\".")
            self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is for Watchkit. Im getting error on self.profileImage.image = UIImage(data: data!). That says "WKInterfaceImage" does not have a member named 'image'

Comment: I just gave you an example..make changes in code as per your need..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, as it may help you:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    var profilePic =  UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://devhumor.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/devhumor.com_pointers.png")));

    self.profileImage.setImage(profilePic);
});
```